# Greenspace data in United Kingdom?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, land-use

I need greenspace data for Brighton and Hove and Dudley areas. Does anyone know where I can get this? I have tried to extract it from OpenStreetMaps but the areas are too large and it crashes before the data is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have data for GB:
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html
There are few shapefiles, greenspace too.